# Query de Pesquisa vinda de um formulário Dinamico (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, query, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com um problema para construir uma QUERY que vem de um formulário dinâmico.

Tenho um formulário de pesquisa em que os campos para pesquisa são dinâmicos (podem ser de texto ou checkbox), ou seja sempre que é adicionado um novo campo tem de ser possível pesquisar por esse campo, alguém me pode dar uma luz de como o fazer?

Obrigado

Comment: me explica uma coisa, como que eh adicionado esses campos na parte da pesquisa?

Comment: através de um outro formulário, numa outra secção do site

Answer (score 1):

Laranja, poderia explicar melhor sua situação?

Pelo que entendi, você possui uma aplicação de tela única e nessa existe campos TextBox e ComboBox, e precisa criar uma query de consulta ao banco com esses campos, quando esses são preenchidos, é isso?

Se sim, uma idéia simples.

Use um if para identificar qual Text ou Combo foi preenchido ou selecionado e preencha a TAG dos campos com o nome das colunas da tabela.
Ex:

```
private void DefineNomeCampos()
    {
        comboBox1.Tag = "COL_TIPOPESSOA";
        textBox1.Tag = "COL_NOMEPESSOA";

    }
    private void PreencheQuery()
    {
        StringBuilder sbSelect = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbWhere = new StringBuilder();

        sbSelect.Append("Select ");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            sbSelect.Append(textBox1.Tag + ",");
            sbWhere.Append(textBox1.Tag + "=" + textBox1.Text + ",");

        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            sbSelect.Append(comboBox1.Tag + ",");
            sbSelect.Append(comboBox1.Tag + "," + comboBox1.SelectedText + "," );

        }
    }
```

Comment: Luiz obrigado pela dica, mas queria uma solução para php (framework codeigniter), no entanto eu tenho uma tela com várias checkbox  e varias caixas de texto, mas esses campos hoje podem ser 10 amanha podem ser 100 e com nomes diferentes, ou seja eu preciso que a query seja montada de forma dinâmica para que sempre que haja um campo novo a query seja feita com esse campo, a parte das validações se um campo esta preenchido ou não eu já resolvi e consigo pegar as caixas de texto pelo o id de cada, mas na hora de montar a query não estou a conseguir em codeigniter